# add items to dictionary of list

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have files with a lines as such, where every row has an index (a,b) and then a list of number associated to them

```
a\t12|123|08340|4985
b\t3856|12|276
```

What i want is to get to this output

```
12    a
123   a
8340  a
4985  a
3856  b
276   b
```

Note that I am only wanting to output a unique set of the genes, with the value of first occurrence in case there are more than one of the same numbers in the rows.

I went about it in this way: by trying to add the numbers to a dictionary with the letter as keys, and the numbers as values. Finally, only outputting the set() of the numbers together with the corresponding letter.

```
uniqueval = set()
d = defaultdict(list)

for line in file:
   fields = line.strip().split(\t)
   Idx = fields[0]
   Values = fields[1].split("|")
   for Val in Values:
       uniqueval.add(Val)
       d[Idx] += Val
       for u in uniqueval:
           print u,"\t", [key for key in d.keys() if u in d.values()]
```

The script runs, but when I look into the dictionary, the Val's are all split by character, as such:

```
 {'a': ['1','2','1'....], 'b': ['3', '8',....]}
```

I don't understand why the Values get split since it's in a for loop, I thought it was going to take each Val as a new value to add to the dict. Could you help me understand this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **extending** your lists with `Val`:

```
d[Idx] += Val
```

This adds each character in `Val` as a separate element.

Use `append()` instead:

```
d[Idx].append(Val)
```

Comment: Thanks -- That works, but I'm not sure why in my case it adds each character since `for Val in Values` means each element out of a list of strings, so Val is 1 string inside each loop... Am I wrong?
Besides that, I just found out that it doesn't create the dictionary I need, somehow a lot of Values are added multiple times, leaving a much longer list-- not sure why.

Comment: `+=` on a list does the same thing as `list.extend()`; taking each *element* and adding those one by one. In a string the elements are individual characters.

Comment: Instead of a list, use a set and `d[Idx].add(Val)` to only collect unique values per `Idx`.

Comment: Ok. I changed the Values to a set by `set(Values)` and then used it within the `for` loop as `d[Idx].add(Val)`, but I get an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'` Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3524881 I was talking about the `defaultdict` factory. You currently have `defaultdict(list)`, make that `defaultdict(set)`.